# Why is my xslt displaying the wrong values in my output even though the xpath is correct?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the relevant portion of my XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE recipeml SYSTEM "recipeml.dtd">
<recipeml>
  <recipe>
    <head>
        <title>Coq au Riesling</title>
    </head>
    <ingredients>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>30</qty>
                <unit system="metric">ml</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>garlic-infused olive oil</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>150</qty>
                <unit system="metric" unit="g">gram(s)</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>bacon lardons</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>1</qty>
            </amt>
            <item>leek(s)</item>
            <prep>(finely sliced)</prep>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>12</qty>
            </amt>
            <item>chicken thighs (boneless and skinned)</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>3</qty>
            </amt>
            <item>bay leaves</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>300</qty>
                <unit system="metric">gram(s)</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>oyster mushroom(s) (torn into strips)</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>750</qty>
                <unit system="metric">ml</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>Riesling</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty> 1</qty>
                <unit>splash of</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>double cream (optional)</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty> 1</qty>
                <unit>pinch of</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>salt</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <unit>pinch of </unit>
            </amt>
            <item>Pepper</item>
        </ing>
        <ing>
            <amt>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <unit>tablespoon(s)</unit>
            </amt>
            <item>dill (chopped to serve (2 tablespoons if needed)) </item>
        </ing>
    </ingredients>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates>

            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>          
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="recipeml/recipe/head/title">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </h3>        
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="recipeml/recipe/ingredients">
    <ul> 
        <xsl:for-each select="ing">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="item"/>
                <ul><xsl:value-of select="//amt/child::qty[not(following-sibling::unit)]"/></ul></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="recipeml/recipe/directions">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(preceding-sibling::step)]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(following-sibling::note)]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is with this line here. I want it to only display the quantity if there is not a unit element. I tested my xpath and it worked but when I apply my scenario it is puts that every item has a quantity of 1.

```
    <ul><xsl:value-of select="//amt/child::qty[not(following-sibling::unit)]"/></ul></li>
```

Here is the output that I am getting:

```
    <html>
      <body>  

  <h3>Coq au Riesling</h3>


  <ul>
     <li>garlic-infused olive oil
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>bacon lardons
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>leek(s)
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>chicken thighs (boneless and skinned)
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>bay leaves
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>oyster mushroom(s) (torn into strips)
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>Riesling
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>double cream (optional)
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>salt
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>Pepper
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
     <li>dill (chopped to serve (2 tablespoons if needed)) 
        <ul>1</ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

What do I need to change to get it to only show the amt for leeks, chicken thighs, and bay leaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path expression starting with "/" or "//" always selects from the root of the tree. You write

```
<xsl:for-each select="ing">
   <li><xsl:value-of select="item"/>
       <ul><xsl:value-of select="//amt/child::qty[not(following-sibling::unit)]"/></ul></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but `amt` is a child of `ing`, so you just want `select="amt/qty[...]"`. You could also write `select="amt[not(unit)]/qty"`.

(Your question, incidentally, holds the clue to the answer. An XPath expression that is correct in one context can be quite incorrect in another. Understanding how XSLT changes the context node for evaluating an XPath expression is critical.)

Incidentally your last template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="recipeml/recipe/directions">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(preceding-sibling::step)]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(following-sibling::note)]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

will never produce any output. The two `xsl:for-each` instructions are empty, so you are saying "for each xxxx, do nothing" - which always does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an adjustment to your setup with templates that walk down the tree (*recipe* level, *ingredients* level, *ing* level) and at the end applies two sets for *ing* nodes.

With this approach, you avoid multiple templates matched from root `recipeml`, use of `xsl:foreach`, use of `following-sibling`, and absolute references with `//`. And be sure to add `<xsl:strip-space>` to remove the whitespaces and line breaks from source XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="recipeml/recipe">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="head/title"/>
                </h3>       
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredients"/>
            </body>          
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ingredients">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ing[not(amt/unit)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ing[amt/unit]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ing[not(amt/unit)]">
        <ul> 
            <li><xsl:value-of select="item"/>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amt/qty"/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ing[amt/unit]">
        <ul> 
            <li><xsl:value-of select="item"/>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CV/1)